# Label adds up to players score at GameOver Scene: Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, c, ios

So I've seen it everywhere in apps/games and other things its when you score or you get game over and the score number adds up to your score from zero. I want it so in about 1 second a label goes from the text: 0 to and integer that is stored with the players score.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go by using an `NSOperation` that sleeps and add the points (actually it may work even without sleeping). Something like:

```
NSInvocationOperation *op = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self 
                                                                 selector:@selector(updateScore)
                                                                   object:nil];
[queue addOperation:[op autorelease]];

-(void)updateScore {
  while (tot < 1.0) {
    displayingScore += score*incr;
    tot += incr;
    // update score label to displayingScore
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.05];
  }
}
```

Comment: Isn't this a bit too much overkill? A timer should work too imo.

Comment: I'm used to write code that should avoid normal iOS timing (Cocos2D), that's why I usually prefer to go this way

Answer (score 2):

Create a `UILabel` to display the score, and use an `NSTimer` to update the `UILabel`'s `text` property.  Apple doesn't ship a class that will do it all for you.

Answer (score 1):

You need two variables; the currentScore and the current score being displayed. You will also need a timer to handle updating the ui.

When your score changes, update currentScore to the final score you want. Then start a timer that increments the displayedScore until it gets there i.e.

```
-(void)scoreUpdater:(NSTimer *)timer {
    // Update the score
    displayScore ++;
    [scoreLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", displayScore]];

    // Have we got there yet?
    if (displayScore == currentScore) {
        [scoreTimer invalidate];
        [scoreTimer release];
        scoreTimer = nil;
    }
}
```